# bootstrap tabs doesn't work correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

do you see where is the issue from this code about my bootstrap tabs ? 
i tried the example code from bootstrap website on the same page and it's working .. :(

**Bootstrap tab :**

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tL0mkqch/

Comment: Did you include `jquery.js`?

Comment: yep, everything is included because i tried the bootstrap example and it's worked properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas,
Please check this link, I fixed the issue. [Working copy](https://jsfiddle.net/hznkjcL1/)

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 mainpage">
                    <form>
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Etape1" aria-controls="Etape1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Etape 1</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Etape2" aria-controls="Etape2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Etape 2</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Etape3" aria-controls="Etape3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Etape 3</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Etape4" aria-controls="Etape4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Etape 4</a></li>
            <!--<li role="presentation"><a href="#Etape5" aria-controls="Etape5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Etape 5</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Etape6" aria-controls="Etape6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Etape 6</a></li>-->
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Etape1">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Information Salarié</h3>
                    </div><!-- .panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="typeEntretien" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type d'entretien</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="form-control" name="typeEntretien" id="typeEntretien">
                                    <option disabled selected>Choisir un type d'entretien</option>
                                    <option value="B">Entretien Biennal</option>
                                    <option value="BEDL">Entretien Biennal + Etat des lieux</option>
                                </select>
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-1_ -->
                        </div><!-- .form-groupe -->
                        <br/><br/>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nomSalarie" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nom</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="form-control" name="nomSalarie" id="idSalarie">
                                    <option disabled selected>Choisir un salarié</option>
                                    <?php while($ligne = $displaySalarie->fetch()){?>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-10 -->
                        </div><!-- .form-groupe -->
                        <div class="salarie"></div> 
                    </div><!-- .panel-body -->
                </div><!-- .panel-default -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Informations Entretien</h3>
                    </div><!-- .panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dateEntretien" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date entretien</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="input-group date dateEntretien" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo date("j-n-Y"); ?>" name="dateEntretien" id="dateEntretien" placeholder="Date de l'entretien" readonly>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                </div><!-- .input-grope -->
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-3 -->
                        </div> <!-- .form-groupe -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="respEntretien" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Chargé(e) d'entretien</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <select class="form-control" name="respEntretien" id="respEntretien">
                                    <option disabled selected>Choisir le responsable de l'entretien</option>
                                    <?php while($ligne = $displayRH->fetch()){?>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-10 -->
                        </div><!-- .form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="datePEntretien" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Entretien précédent </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group date datePEntretien" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly name="datePEntretien" id="datePEntretien" placeholder="Date du précedent entretien">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                </div><!-- .input-group -->
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-4 -->
                            <label for="dateEDLP" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etat des lieux précédent </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="input-group date dateEDLP" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly name="dateEDLP" id="dateEDLP" placeholder="Date du précedent état des lieux">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                </div><!-- .input-group -->
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-4 -->
                        </div> <!-- .form-group -->                                 
                    </div><!-- .panel-body -->
                </div><!-- .panel-default -->
            </div><!-- #Etape1 -->
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Etape2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Poste occupé</h3>
                    </div><!-- .panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Le contenu du poste de travail a-t-il évolué depuis le dernier EP ?</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="choixContenuPP" id="OContenuPP" value="1"> Oui
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="choixContenuPP" id="NContenuPP" value="0"> Non
                                </label>
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-5 -->
                        </div><!-- .form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group" id="divTAchoixContenuPP" style="display:none;">
                            <label for="TAchoixContenuPP" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Si oui, préciser les principaux changements </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="TAchoixContenuPP" id="TAchoixContenuPP" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
                        </div><!-- .form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Le salarié a-t-il changé de poste depuis le dernier entretien &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;?</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="choixchangement" id="OChangement" value="1"> Oui
                                </label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" name="choixchangement" id="NChangement" value="0"> Non
                                </label>
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-5 -->
                        </div><!-- .form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group" id="divTAchoixChangement" style="display:none;">
                            <label for="TAchoixContenuPP" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Si oui, indiquer le nouveau contenu du poste </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="TAchoixChangement" id="TAchoixChangement" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
                            </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
                        </div><!-- .form-group -->
                    </div><!-- .panel-body -->
                </div> <!-- .panel-default -->       
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Formations suivies</h3>
                    </div><!-- .panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="formation"></div>
                    </div><!-- .panel-body -->
                </div><!-- .panel-default -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Bénéfice des formations suivies<sup>*</sup></h3>
                    </div><!-- .panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
                                <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>N</td>
                                        <td>Compétence acquises</td>
                                        <td>Certification ou Diplôme obtenu(e)</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="table-striped">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table><!-- .table -->
                        </div><!-- .table-responsive -->
                    </div><!-- .panel-body -->
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <span style="font-size:11px;"><sup>*</sup>Rappeler le numéro de la formation</span>
                    </div><!-- .panel-footer -->
                </div><!-- .panel-default -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Compétences</h3>
                    </div><!-- .panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
                                    <tbody class="table-striped">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">4 Compétences les mieux maîtrisées dans le poste</td>
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_Acompet1" id="user_Acompet1" placeholder="Compétence 1">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_Acompet2" id="user_Acompet2" placeholder="Compétence 2">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_Acompet3" id="user_Acompet3" placeholder="Compétence 3">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>4</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_Acompet4" id="user_Acompet4" placeholder="Compétence 4">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table><!-- .table -->
                            </div><!-- .table-responsive -->
                        </div><!-- .col-md-6 -->
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
                                    <tbody class="table-striped">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">4 Compétences les moins maîtrisées dans le poste*</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_NAcompet1" id="user_NAcompet1" placeholder="Compétence 1">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="AD1" id="AD1" value="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_NAcompet2" id="user_NAcompet2" placeholder="Compétence 2">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="AD2" id="AD2" value="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_NAcompet3" id="user_NAcompet3" placeholder="Compétence 3">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="AD3" id="AD3" value="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>4</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <input type="text" size="50" class="form-control" name="user_NAcompet4" id="user_NAcompet4" placeholder="Compétence 4">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="AD4" id="AD4" value="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table><!-- .table -->
                            </div><!-- .table-responsive -->
                        </div><!-- .col-md-6 -->
                    </div><!-- .panel-body -->
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <span style="font-size:11px;"><sup>*</sup><span style="font-size:11px;">Cocher si la compétence est à developper</span>
                    </div><!-- .panel-footer -->
                </div><!-- .panel-default -->
            </div><!-- Etape2 -->
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Etape3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Evolution du contenu du poste</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="evoPrevisible" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Evolution prévisible du poste (organisation, missions, objectifs, outils…) d’ici 2 ans</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="evoPrevisible" id="evoPrevisible" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="competenceDev" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Compétences à acquérir et/ou à développer d’ici 2 ans :</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="competenceDev" id="evoPrevisible" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Dispositif de formation pouvant être utilisé pour <br/> acquérir et/ou développer les compétences : </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="VAEP" id="VAEP" value="VAEP"> VAE
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="CPFP" id="CPFP" value="CPFP"> CPF
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td rowspan="0">
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="PDFP" id="PDFP" value="PDFP"> Plan de formation
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="CIFP" id="CIFP" value="CIFP"> CIF
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="PDPP" id="PDPP" value="PDPP"> Période de professionnalisation
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Etape4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Projet professionnel du salarié</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
                                <tbody class="table-striped">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td rowspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">Le salarié a-t-il un projet professionnel ?</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="LEP" id="LEP" value="LEP"> à Limousin Expansion
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="CRLP" id="CRLP" value="CRLP"> au Conseil Régional du Limousin
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="EXP" id="EXP" value="EXP"> a l'extérieur
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="PDPP" id="PDPP" value="PDPP"> pas de projet professionnel
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align: middle;">Dispositif de formation pouvant être utilisé pour <br/> acquérir et/ou développer les compétences : </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="VAES" id="VAES" value="VAES"> VAE
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="CPFS" id="CPFS" value="CPFS"> CPF
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td rowspan="0">
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="PDFS" id="PDFS" value="PDFS"> Plan de formation
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="CIFS" id="CIFS" value="CIFS"> CIF
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="PDPS" id="PDPS" value="PDPS"> Période de professionnalisation
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" name="submit_entpro" id="submit_entpro" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Compare your code with mine and see whats the problem.